# Writing ArrayList of objects to textfile using filter

Tags: java, arraylist, filewriter

(Disclaimer: I am not done writing the coding, so I have been using lousy names to 
identify things.)

I have an ArrayList of *PersonObject*s called *PersonIndex*.
The parameters of the *PersonObject*s are as follows: Name, Age, Gender, Height.

What I am trying to do is process the list and depending on what the last name starts with, it gets written to a different text file.

Because it is in bad taste to try combining three write methods to one writer, I have three different ones which are then called into a single method.

That method is as follows:

```
public void fullWriteNames(){
    writeNamesA2K();
    writeNamesL2R();
    writeNamesS2Z();
}
```

I know the general layout of the writer method which is as follows:

```
String stopper = "stop";
    try{
        personWriter = new FileWriter(fileName2, true);
        personWriter.write(*stuff to write*);
        personWriter.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        System.out.println("Error.");
    }
```

The issue I am having is how to use an if statement by the .write line to filter the objects. I know I need to use .startsWith, but otherwise I am clueless.

Any help would be appreciated. If there is any coding I left out here which would be relevant, please let me know.

Comment: Why not supply a "filter" to a single write method which can check if the object should be written to it?  You could use something like a regular expression if your filters are more complex then `startsWith` or `endsWith` or `contains`...

Comment: Because until you just mentioned it, I had no idea that was possible.

Comment: @Frog6666 , I don't understand. Can you make your question clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since characters are really just numbers, you could do something like this:

```
public void fullWriteNames() {
    char first = lastname.charAt(0);

    if (first >= 'A' && first <= 'K') 
        writeNamesA2K();
    else if (first >= 'L' && first <= 'R')
        writeNamesL2R();
    else if (first >= 'S' && first <= 'Z')
        writeNamesS2Z();
}
```

I'm assuming here that the `lastname` variable is your `PersonObject`'s last name.

Comment: I've been implementing your suggestion while not talking to a Google employee about something totally irrelevant, but I will be sure to let you know if it worked and how I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match a group

```
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(25);
    names.add("Apple");
    names.add("apple");
    names.add("bannas");
    names.add("Kings");
    names.add("Nov");
    names.add("Nov");
    names.add("Yak");

    for (String name : names) {
        if (name.matches("[A-Ka-k].*")) {
            System.out.println("[A-K] " + name);
        } else if (name.matches("^[L-Rl-r].*")) {
            System.out.println("[L-R] " + name);
        } else if (name.matches("^[S-Zs-z].*")) {
            System.out.println("[S-Z] " + name);
        }
    }
```

This might allow you to set up a write method which could take a "filter" parameter and make the decisions what to do based on the filter

```
public void writeToFile(List<Person> listOfNames, File fileToWrite, String filter) {
    ...
}
```

Which you could call using something like...

```
 writeToFile(listOfPeople, fileForGroupAToK, "[A-Ka-k].*");
```

Personally, though, I might be tempered to generate groups of lists based on the filter which might be a little faster then iterating over the entire list 3 times...but that's me ;)